# Force Capybara to fail on unexpected modals

Tags: modal-dialog, capybara, google-chrome-headless

I'm some tests to trigger and validate a JS alert like this:

```
it 'triggers a modal' do
  accept_alert('Hello world') do
    visit '/'
    click_button 'Button'
  end
end
```

Which is failing on:

```
 Capybara::ModalNotFound:
       Unable to find modal dialog with Hello world
```

When running headlessly, I thought that the dialog wasn't triggered at all and it was an issue with my JS code but I noticed the test log listed:

```
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3001
Modal window has been opened, but you didn't wrap your code into (`accept_prompt` | `dismiss_prompt` | `accept_confirm` | `dismiss_confirm` | `accept_alert`), accepting by default
F
```

Running in full Chrome I noticed that the modal is being triggered and with the expected message. So now I'm not sure:

- why my `accept_alert` isn't failing the test if the message is actually wrong (e.g. there are hidden characters included and the message is actually `Hello world\t`. or something)
- how is an unwrapped modal since my accept block wraps the whole test body?

I might have a silly syntax error, but I think the above is right & is working on another test. To try and get to the bottom of it, I wanted to disable Capybara's "accepting by default".

Is there any way to:

1. Make any unexpected modal fail the test (instead of accept/dismiss)?
2. Log out the text of modals as they occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepting by default isn't being done by Capybara it's being done be the driver you're using (Cuprite I'm assuming based on the message being produced). If you wrap the action that causes the modal to appear (based on behavior exhibited I'm assuming the `visit`) rather than the whole test then it will raise an error if the error message isn't correct
since the `accept_alert` method is only expecting the modal once the block has finished expecting

```
accept_alert('Hello world') do
  visit '/'
end
click_button 'Button'
```

The behavior of auto-accepting (with warning) unexpected alerts is due to its original design being based on the Poltergeist and I don't believe is configurable currently.

Comment: thanks, when I reduced the scope of the `accept_alert` it did stop auto-accepting (didn't realise that wrapping two commands would cause it to misbehave) and there was another alert I wasn't expecting so resolved now. Didn't realise that it was the driver that did the accepting (but that makes sense alright) and good to know that it's not configurable and I'm not just missing something.